# LastNonEmpty in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, business-intelligence, olap

How I can replace behavior of LastNonEmpty Aggregate Function in MDX? When I want to use it, I get:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error      Errors related to
>   feature availability and configuration: The 'Semi-additive measures'
>   feature is not included in the '64 Bit Standard' edition of Analysis
>   Services.         0

Comment: That feature is only available with Enterprise Edition.There are plenty of articles how to reproduce the same behaviour with MDX.

Comment: I tried http://thinknook.com/ssas-lastnonempty-aggregation-function-2012-08-18/ but I get error when I put SCOPE in MDX calculation code. Do you have any example?

Answer (score 2):

Chris Webb has a fast approach here: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2011/03/24/last-ever-non-empty-a-new-fast-mdx-approach/

```
WITH 

MEMBER MEASURES.DAYSTODATE AS 
COUNT(NULL:[Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER)-1

MEMBER MEASURES.HADSALE AS 
IIF([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]=0, NULL, MEASURES.DAYSTODATE)

MEMBER MEASURES.MAXDATE AS 
MAX(NULL:[Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER, MEASURES.HADSALE)

MEMBER MEASURES.LASTSALE AS
IIF(ISEMPTY(MEASURES.MAXDATE), NULL, 
([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
[Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS.ITEM(MEASURES.MAXDATE)))


SELECT 
HEAD([Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS, 10)
*
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
,MEASURES.[LASTSALE]} 
ON 0,
[Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS
ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Or within the cube script then he uses this:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.MEASURES.DAYSTODATE AS 
COUNT(NULL:[Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER)-1
, VISIBLE=FALSE;

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.MEASURES.HADSALE AS 
IIF([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]=0, NULL, MEASURES.DAYSTODATE)
, VISIBLE=FALSE;

SCOPE(MEASURES.MAXDATE, [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS); 
    THIS = MAX(NULL:[Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER, MEASURES.HADSALE);
END SCOPE;

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.MEASURES.LASTSALE AS
IIF(ISEMPTY(MEASURES.MAXDATE), NULL, 
([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
[Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS.ITEM(MEASURES.MAXDATE)));
```

Comment: I copied this code (with changed measure) and I get: The '[MAXDATE]' member was not found in the cube when the string, [MEASURES].[MAXDATE], was parsed.&The END SCOPE statement does not match the opening SCOPE statement.

Comment: he has MaxDate as a real measure in the cube - the scoped assignment overwrites it: https://cwebbbi.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/image3.png

Comment: Do you know any details about this measure (what should I create)?